# Create/destroy multiple threads for animations/light effects

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm developing a program for the Razer Deathadder and Firefly, I am going to create new light effects for the Firefly. I'm doing this in C# with the Colore library.

Now these light effects will be created using Threads with `while(true)` statements but how can I check and destroy threads and then reactivate them again when the user has pressed a button/radiobutton?

Right now the threads are either going over each other or getting deactivated and won't "turn on" again, is there a simpler way to do this?

- I haven't tried anything other than creating functions to kill the threads but then they will not activate again.

This is how I have done it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Thread effect = new Thread(new ThreadStart((Effect));
    effect.Start();
}

private void Effect() {
    while(true) {
       // lightning effect will go here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using threads for this is an overkill, especially since (I'm assuming) those threads will stay idle most of the time.

Instead, what you can do is to use `async`-`await` to be more efficient. If you really need to run the code on a separate thread from the current one, you can use `Task.Run()` for that.

To control whether the code is enabled or not, you don't need to stop the code, you can just pause it.

To achieve that, you can either periodically check whether the code is enabled:

```
while (true)
{
    if (isEffectEnabled)
    {
        // lightning effect will go here
    }
    else
    {
        await Task.Delay(someReasonableDelay);
    }
}
```

Or you can use [`AsyncManualResetEvent` from the AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncManualResetEvent) that lets you wait until the effect is enabled:

```
while (true)
{
    await isEffectEnabledEvent.WaitAsync();
    // lightning effect will go here
}
```

Comment: and i can do this to like 4 or 5 more light effects?

Comment: Sure, but if you're running multiple threads at the same time, you have to be careful about synchronizing access to any shared data properly.